# Zoom on touch event

Tags: lua, touch, zooming, coronasdk

I'm trying to put in place a zoom function on touch event. I scale the parent group using transition.to and onComplete move it to the event center. But then at one point it just jumps to the parent group origin. Any ideas?

I'm now pasting a shortened version of the code.

```
local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()
physics.setContinuous( false )
--physics.setScale( 60 )



local height = display.contentHeight
local width = display.contentWidth



local backGround = display.newRect( 0,0,width,height )
backGround:setFillColor(91,91,91)

local allElements = display.newGroup()  
local grip = {}
local gripSize = {
-- w: gripwidth, h: gripheight, s: strength required
{w=30, h=20, s=1},
{w=20, h=10, s=1.5},
{w=10, h=10, s=2},
}

local r

local function createTexture()
    local originX = 0
    local originY = height -75
    for i=0,50 do
        r = math.random(3)
        local x = originX + math.random(width)
        local y = originY - math.random(2*height)
        grip[i] = display.newRect( allElements, x, y, gripSize[r].w, gripSize[r].h)
        grip[i].size = gripSize[r].s
        if (r == 1) then
        grip[i]:setFillColor(51,255,0)
        elseif (r == 2) then
        grip[i]:setFillColor(255,51,51)
        elseif (r == 3) then
        grip[i]:setFillColor(51,51,255)
        end

    end
end 

createTexture()



wallBottom = display.newRect( allElements, 0,height-20,width,20)
physics.addBody(wallBottom, "static", { density=5, friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 } )

head = display.newCircle( allElements, width/2,50,20 )
physics.addBody( head, { density=5, friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 } )


local touchBorder = 20

local function calcTouchOffset( e )
    local x, y = 0, 0

    if (e.x < touchBorder) then
        x = e.x - touchBorder
    elseif (e.x > width-touchBorder) then
        x = e.x - (width-touchBorder)
    end

    if (e.y < touchBorder) then
        y = e.y - touchBorder
    elseif (e.y > height-touchBorder) then
        y = e.y - (height-touchBorder)
    end

    return x, y
end


local function startDrag( e )
    local body = e.target
    local phase = e.phase
    local stage = display.getCurrentStage()

    if (e.phase == "began") then
        e.target.bodyType = "dynamic"
        e.target.hasFocus = true
        local x, y = allElements:contentToLocal( e.x, e.y )
        e.target.touchjoint = physics.newJoint( "touch", e.target, x, y )
        stage:setFocus( e.target )
        transition.to( allElements, { time = 200, x= -body.x, y= -body.y, xScale = 2, yScale = 2,})
        xOffset, yOffset = 0, 0
        return true
    elseif (e.target.hasFocus) then
        if (e.phase == "moved") then

            local x,y = allElements:contentToLocal(e.x, e.y)     -- This line is changed
            e.target.touchjoint:setTarget( x, y )               -- This line is changed
            xOffset, yOffset = calcTouchOffset( e )
        else
            transition.to( allElements, { time = 200, x = body.x, y = body.y, xScale = 1, yScale = 1,  })
            e.target.hasFocus = false
            e.target.touchjoint:removeSelf()
            e.target.touchjoint = nil
            stage:setFocus( nil )
            xOffset, yOffset = 0, 0

        end
        return true
    end
    xOffset, yOffset = 0, 0
    return false

end

head:addEventListener( "touch", startDrag )

    function allElements:update()   


    allElements.x, allElements.y = allElements.x - xOffset, allElements.y - yOffset
    allElements.x, allElements.y = allElements.x, allElements.y
    if (allElements.x > -startX) and ( startX < 0 ) then
        allElements.x = -startX
    elseif ( routeW < width ) then
        allElements.x = 0   
    elseif ( allElements.x < startX ) and ( startX < 0 ) then
        allElements.x = startX
    end
    --[[if (allElements.x > 0) then
        allElements.x = 0
    elseif ( routeW < width ) then
        allElements.x = 0       
    elseif ( allElements.x < (width-routeW) ) and ( routeW > width ) then
        allElements.x = width-routeW
    end ]]--    

    if (allElements.y > (routeH-height)) and ( routeH > height ) then
        allElements.y = routeH-height
    elseif ( routeH < height ) then
        allElements.y = 0
    elseif (allElements.y < 0) then
        allElements.y = 0
    end

end


function enterFrame()
    allElements:update()
end
```

Comment: Can you create a complete example that can run? You have a lot going on that isn't related and it's easier to debug if you only have one problem to look at. Your transition.to on touch is using `x= -body.x` so you move `allElements` left `body.x` units. Then on complete you use `x = -body.x` again, thus moving `allElements` to the left `body.x` units again. Also, in your touch release handler you do a `transition.to` again which will mess up any already running transitions from the initial touch.

Comment: I will create a sample. I was trying to get make an effect like zoom the area, where the touch event happens. This is why on "begin" I put one transition in and on release I scale down the group. x = -body.x is used to focus the scaling. Otherwise it the scaling goes from the groups upper left corner point.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update this part:

```
elseif (e.target.hasFocus) then
    if (e.phase == "moved") then

        local x,y = allElements:contentToLocal(e.x, e.y)     -- This line is changed
        e.target.touchjoint:setTarget( x, y )               -- This line is changed
        xOffset, yOffset = calcTouchOffset( e )
    else
        transition.to( allElements, { time = 200, x = 0, y = 0, xScale = 1, yScale = 1,  })
        e.target.hasFocus = false
        e.target.touchjoint:removeSelf()
        e.target.touchjoint = nil
        stage:setFocus( nil )
        xOffset, yOffset = 0, 0

    end
    return true
end
```

By replacing x=body.x by x=0 and y=body.y by y=0

Cheers :)